# Change VS Intellisense statement completion behavior order

Tags: c#, intellisense, vsix

i currently developing a customize intellisense project. The intellisense have the current behaviour by calling `ICompletionSource` then follow by `ISignatureHelpSource`.

> ICompletionSource: Provides completions for a given content type.
>
> ISignatureHelpSource: Defines a provider of signature help information that is used in the IntelliSense process.

Is that a way i can reverse the order?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that a way i can reverse the order?

I can't see how.

If say you have an empty text file whose VSIX supports, as soon as you start typing (anything but a <kbd>(</kbd>) the **statement completion (SC)** providers are given a chance to offer suggestions.  They are responsible for things like keywords; modifiers; class names; <kbd>{</kbd>; <kbd>}</kbd>; and so forth.

However, as soon as you type a <kbd>(</kbd>, **signature help (SH)** providers are then given a chance to offer suggestions based on a recogised method name.  The providers **return help information for any signatures for the method name recognised (if any)**.

They both serve very different purposes.  When done correctly, it is the SC providers which list what different "methods" (`Boing(); Bounce(); Ping();`) are available, and once you make a choice the SH display what arguments are required.

You could create your own file type which is only recogised by your VSIX and have any combination of statement completion + signature help support.

i.e. it is entirely possible to only have signature help but **no** statement completion. [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-signature-help?view=vs-2015)